# Firebase: responding to http POST request

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I was thinking of import my server Java code to firebase, basically replace my Dynamic web app with Jeresy and mongoDB to Firebase using hosting and functions .
I have implemented the sendWelcomeEmail and sendByeEmail with events user.created and user.deleted.

But now I want to do something more complicated.
Based on post request that comes from the mobile I want to extract the JSON data and then update the DataBase.

So I created js file with plenty of functions but now I am not sure it will actually work.
Is that the best way to implement this workflow.

The workflow goes like this.

Image is taken on the android device => extract information from image ==> upload the Json Data to the server (Firebase Hosting) => functions is been execute is response to POST request ==> extarct the data ==> save it to the Firebase Database.

Let me know if this sound ok, or I need to implent another workflow.
Thanks
Eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea of Firebase is that your app talks directly to backend services (such as the database, or cloud storage), and you only write server-side code (with cloud functions) for functionality that Firebase doesn't provide a client-side API for.

Why don't you simply let the Android client write directly to the Firebase Database?

Comment: I need to do lots of math calculation before writing to the DB.
And android is not the only device loading the raw data.
So think of json RAW data upload from different devices including not mobile, then the server gets data do all the math and write to the DB.
in your way I will need to take all the math to each client device, but I have clients which Firebase SDK does not run on them.

Comment: Pre-processing data in a HTTP-trigger Cloud Functions is a valid approach. Alternatively you can let the clients write the raw data to the database, then use a database-triggered Cloud Function to process that data. There is no right or wrong between these, it all depends on the use-case and personal preferences.

Comment: Frank Thank you :-)

Comment: I have implemented my workflow, and they are DB records on Firebase.
I am happy :-)